# get user details from telegram if only mobile number is provided

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

How can I get `telegram` user_detail if know only the mobile number.
When a user signs_up to telegram, telegram returns an object which included user_id and access_hash. 
So that if i need to send message to user, i will only need telegram user_id and hash to send message to that user.

```
     client.send_message(InputPeerUser(u.id, u.access_hash), "hi")
```

Now for a users whose only number is provided how can i get his id and access_hash si that i can send message to user by telegram API

Answer (score 2):

you should first add phone number to your contact list, the returned result from telegram will contain the ID and Access_hash:

```
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=phone, first_name="", last_name="")
result = client(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
usrDict = result.__dict__["users"]
if usrDict:
    chatID = usrDict[0].__dict__["id"]
    access_hash = usrDict[0].__dict__["access_hash"]
```